# What is the "endpoint" in flask's .add_url_rule()?

Tags: python, flask

Consider the following code

```
import flask

class API:
    def hello(self):
        return flask.Response('hello', 200)

api = API()
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.add_url_rule('/', 'hello', api.hello)
app.run()
```

It returns "hello" upon a `GET` call to `/`.

The [documentation for `add_url_rule`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule) states that

> [`add_url_rule`] works exactly like the `route()` decorator.

It requires however at least three parameters. The first and third one are understandable and mimic `@route()`. What is the second one (`hello` in my case)?

The documentation further states that this is

> **endpoint** – the endpoint for the registered URL rule. Flask itself assumes the name of the view function as endpoint

What does this mean? Why isn't the URL (`/`) and the method to call (`api.hello`) sufficient? What is the role of the "endpoint"? How is it exactly used?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's the *name* for the route; the one you'd use in the [`url_for()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for) for example. The endpoint name is the registration key for views, a symbolic name by which you can reference the route from other parts of your application.

`@route()` takes the same parameter; the default is the name of the decorated function. This is documented both in the `add_url_rule()` documentation as well as the documentation for [`@route()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.route):

> - **endpoint** – the endpoint for the registered URL rule. ***Flask itself assumes the name of the view function as endpoint.***

(bold italic emphasis mine).

Note that the example in the documentation tried to show the same:

> Basically this example:
>
> ```
> @app.route('/')
> def index():
>     pass
> ```
>
> Is equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> def index():
>     pass
> app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)
> ```

Note that the second argument `'index'` matches the function name.

Comment: Yes, this is what I read in the documentation, I am trying to understand how this is useful vs. just the URL and the called method. You mentioned `url_for` - I am reading the doc for it (and try to understand the rationale in "Three good reasons for it"). Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @WoJ: because a short symbolic name trumps a url path that could have patterns in it. The symbolic name is less likely to change as your requirements change.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the Flask just updated arguments for `add_url_rule`. 
since this is marked as accepted, should you update the answer? to avoid confusing for next viewer, like me

Answer (score 1):

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


class API:
    def __init__(self):
        app.add_url_rule("/", view_func=self.hello)

    def hello(self):
        return flask.Response("hello", 200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    API()
    app.run()
```

Try this. If you want to run flask pass the variable to class and inside class run the application.